# How restore correct state of view after minimize and restore application?

Tags: android, mosby

I try to use Mosby. But I have one problem.

I have Activity (view), presenter, model, and viewState.
On activity I have button. When I click on button I call the method from presenter to load data:

```
presenter.loadData()
```

Method that load data call 2 methods:

1.`view.showProgress`

2. `model.getData()`

Method `model.getData()` create **ASYNC** http request (Retrofit). After request finish than presenter call method from view, `view.hideProgress()`.

OK. This scheme works fine.

But I have one problem.
Steps:

1.Click button on view

2.`presenter.loadData()`

3.In presenter call `view.showProgress()` and start **async** http request

4.Minimize application

5.Activity is destroy

6.As result on viewState call method `saveInstanceState()` to save current state of view (progress is show)

7.After 5 seconds the network request was finished and presenter try to call `view.hideProgress()`

8.But Activity does not exist and as result, nothing happened.

9.User return to application

10. As result call method in viewState `restoreInstanceState()`
11. And as result progress show again, because this state saved on viewState (see item 6).

The problem is that the progress must be hidden because network request was successfully finished when application was minimized (not visible for the user).

How can I fix problem?

Comment: `saveInstanceState()` doesn't called after app minimized, isn't it? Only at the time of minimizing, but all changes in UI after that will be lost

Answer (score 0):

When you receive `HTTP` response you should store it somewhere, for example, it can be `repository` which stores in memory, or maybe some `local` storage. Then when you call `model.getData()` you should check if data is already saved, return this data from the model (and if needed send one more `HTTP` request to get fresher data) if there is no saved data - send `HTTP` request.
So now, when activity opens you invoke `presenter.getData()`, it calls `view.showProgress()` inside and `model.getData()`, model returns some cached data (if available) and `presented` calls `view.hideProgress()`

Comment: Not help, because I create async http request. So the in method `ifViewAttached(OfferDetailsView::setDownloadMode);` the method `setDownloadMode` not call